# Angular - input field keydown event not working

Tags: angular, input, keydown

When I use following input field it works fine (I can type input) -

```
<input
      maxlength="100"
      placeholder="search products"
      (input)="searchInput($event.target.value)">
```

But when add (keydown) event - input field does not take input -

```
<input
      maxlength="100"
      placeholder="search products"
      (keydown)="search($event)"
      (input)="searchInput($event.target.value)">
```

Here are demo functions -

```
search(event){
  let value = event.target.value;

  this.router.navigate(['/search'], { queryParams: { value } });
}

searchInput(value){
  console.log('value', value);
}
```

I think, I am missing something. Thanks in advance!

Here is a demo in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-keydown-event)

Comment: you are using keydown event not directive, Are you getting any error?

Comment: No I don't get any error

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Yes, I'll create one and post here. Thank you

Comment: I added a stackblitz url

Comment: Since you returing false when the value is empty , you are not able to type next value

Comment: I supposed to have `(keydown.enter)` not `(keydown)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201523/discussion-between-chellappan-and-user3384985).

Comment: Stackblitz seems to be working fine?

Comment: Issue is fixed @AJT82